# Error con la descarga de Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Buenas, tengo un problemita... Hace poco realizé un formateo a mi PC y cuando comencé a instalar de nueva cuenta mis programas, tuve un error con el Eclipse.
Me descargué e instalé el JDK y el JRE en sus versiones más actualizadas, pero al ejecutar el instalador de Eclipse me redirige a la página de Eclipse y me muestra un mensaje en pantalla que dice "Java for Windows is missing"...

¿Alguien sabe qué puedo hacer?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir una captura del navegador cuando te lleva a la página de Eclipse? ¿Que versión de Windows tienes? ¿Y de Java? ¿De 32 o 64 bits?

Comment: que version de eclipse es? 32bit o 64bit?

Comment: Tal vez descargaste una versión es que no es para tu pc.

Comment: Debes revisar la versión de tu PC y descargar la correcta version de Eclipse que puede ser de 32Bits o 64Bits.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que tu variable de entorno `JAVA_HOME` esta apuntando correctamente al JDK. Si es así descargate el paquete sin instalador y comprueba que también está bien en el archivo `eclipse.ini` (la variable `-vm "C:/ruta-a-jdk/bin"`). Si necesitas ayuda con eso ponme un comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Tines que descargar el jdk *(java development kit)* dependiendo de tu arquitectura. Puede ser de 32 o 64 bits. [Download JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Luego descarga el eclipse dependiendo de tu arquitectura. Puede ser de 32 o 64 bits. [Donwload Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

Abre una ventana de comandos y teclea el comando:

java -version

si va bien, tienes java OK, sino NO (intenta reinstalar java en el windows, y reiniciar).

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, en una de las tantas respuestas de stackOverflow en inglés la gran mayoría coincide en que es un problema de arquitectura, te cito una de las respuestas [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603276/11335797) y te dejo una imagen de referencia sobre cual debes instalar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]